# Running script 'skript_name' gives error: Undefined function or variable 'skript_name' in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, undefined

When I try to run a script either using the point-and-click way or `run skript_name` I get the error message: "Undefined function or variable 'skript_name'."

However, using `pwd` I have checked that I am in the correct directory. In addition, the commands `help skript_name` and `exist skript_name` yield sensible results.

I am not an advanced programmer so I might just be overlooking something trivial, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How about `which skript_name`? Does it return the path of the file in your current directory?

Comment: Is the extension of your script file `.m`?

Comment: Can u replicate this with some other script, that just contains, e.g. `disp('Helo world');` or something very simple?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved a similar problem.

1. I added the current folder to path([path documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)).
2. I tried 'which skript_name' and it gave me the correct folder.

But it still showed the same error. My problem was that my skript_name had a hyphen('-') in the file name. Matlab does not like hyphens([here](http://staff.washington.edu/jon/matlab-prog.html)). I changed the file name and it worked.